# MVC prevent unauthorized posts to database

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, security

I made a website that lets my friends play chess with me using ASP.net MVC.  For this website I have a database that keeps track of the status of the games including whether the game is in progress or not.  One of my more nefarious friends decided to write her own html file that has a submit button to post her own custom hidden fields to my database to change a loss to a win. How do I prevent people from doing this?

Her html looks like this:

```
<html>
<form action="http://website.net/chess/game/24" method="post">
    <input type="submit" vale="REQUEST DRAW">
    <input style="display: none;" id="StatusID" value="I win, you lose">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the `[Authorize]` and `[ValidateAntForgeryToken]` on your POST method.

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="StatusID" value="I win, you lose"> Try this oine